# Path from one website to another in Visual Studio debug mode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a solution with two websites (folder based) and two class libraries.  I need to be able to dynamically set a path from one of the websites to the other.  More specifically, I am setting the PostBackUrl property of an image button that is in a datagrid row.  Building and setting the URL for the production environment is easy.  But in the development environment - where each project runs on a different port - it is a bit more confusing.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to store the base urls in the web.config file and change based on the environment they'll be running under.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup up VS to use IIS for debugging - that way it would be the same as your production environment.

Comment: Agreed... that's the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IIS for setting up your web site or assign a fixed port by setting "Use Dynamic Ports" to false under [web site properties](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/19/tip-trick-how-to-run-a-root-site-with-the-local-web-server-using-vs-2005-sp1.aspx).